# python np.where equivalent

Tags: python, numpy

My python skills are not sophisticated but how do I use numpy where to get the elements rather than the indices here?

So in the example below (with mock data), I want the same results from where that the loop gives?

```
import numpy as np

#make some mock data
test=np.ones((10,10))
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
       test[i,j]=i*2.0+j

for i in range(0,10):
    if 8.0<=test[i,5]<=18.0:
            print test[i,5]

print np.where((test[:,5] >= 8.0) & (test[:,5] <=18.0))
```

Comment: `test[(test[:,5] >= 8.0) & (test[:,5] <=18.0)]` ?

Comment: test[(np.where((test[:,5] >= 8.0) & (test[:,5] <=18.0))),5]  works!! Thanks so much MaxU for the idea :)

Comment: BTW: your initialization for-loop can be replaced by `np.arange(10) + np.arange(0, 2*10, 2)[:,None]`

Comment: Thanks  juanpa.arrivillaga !